# Image changing size on zoom with both firefox and chrome using .fadein / .fadeout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have started building a website and implemented a fading image rotation, but when I use Ctrl + z to zoom in and out of the website to test how other setups will view it the image shrinks right down while the main image remains the same size.

Code that may help HTML

```
<div id="main">

    <article id="me" class="panel">
        <header>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <p>Hi There</p>
            </header>
            <a href="#services" class="jumplink pic">
            <span class="arrow icon fa-chevron-right"><span>Hello</span></span>
            <div class="fadein">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            </a>
   </article>
```

CSS

```
    #me .pic {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }

    #me .pic:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: url("images/overlay.png");
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #main {
        width: 45em;
        background: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    }

    .panel {
        padding: 3.5em 2.5em 3.5em 2.5em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 45em;
    }
```